# Print content based on setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, printing

I have a requirement to build an application that will print an ID card.  The application will have two pages:

1. A Settings page to select the layout of the ID card,
2. A Print Page where the user information like name,age etc will be captured.  It will show a preview of the ID Card based on the layout selected on the Settings page.  Upon clicking print, the ID card should be printed.

If the layout in the Settings page has been changed, the same should be effective while we print the ID card.

Here is what I have done:

- In the Settings page I saved the selection of the ID card layout to a table, and in the Print page I will have all the layouts present in the Setting page.  On retrieving the selection made by user in the Setting page I will choose the layout and Print.
- However, if the layout in the Setting page is increased, I need to copy all of that to the printing page.

I don't think this a good way of doing this.

Could you guide me through this.

Comment: I think this question is really too broad.

Comment: What do you mean by broad? Isn't this a place where you can get help? @mok

Comment: Of course it is. But you've asked for the whole technology stack required to implement a (part of a) project. I encourage you to ask your questions here, but you need to be more specific, implement something yourself and when you got stuck ask for help here. Obviously your answer could be answered here but the answers will be mainly based on people's point of views, expertise,conventions,... .

Comment: Ok,I am totally lost.Just throw some light. I don't know what to do next,If you could tel me atleast the steps that I have to do would be heplful,cant even try google without knowing what I have to do next. @mok

Answer (score 0):

The information that you have a need to save between these two different web pages is known as application "state" information.  You as the developer must cause application state information to be stored somewhere between calls to the application's web pages because the web server is intrinsically stateless and will not automatically save this information for you.

When using ASP.NET to build an application, there are many places where application state information can be maintained, but the following three are most prevalent and straightforward to use.  These are discussed below:

- On the web server
- On the client in the browser
- In a database accessible to the web application

***Storing Web Application State on the Web Server***

An ASP.NET web server makes available an object known as the "session" variable.  The session object provides the developer a place where state information can be temporarily saved.  I say temporarily, because if the session object is not accessed within a predefined amount of time that particular session object is destroyed and reclaimed by the system.  By default, this is 20 minutes, though it can be adjusted at the application scope (search for ASP.NET session timeout).

***Storing Web Application State in the Client's Web Browser***

Web browsers allow the developer to maintain web application state information in something known as "cookies".  A cookie is associated with a specific web page, web application path, or web site.  Once again, this is determined by the developer of the web application by setting properties of the cookie.  When the User surfs to the web page or path associated with the cookie, the cookie information is automatically transmitted in the HTTP request for the web page.  ASP.NET then makes that cookie information available to the web page via the "Cookies" collection.  This allows the developer to access that information within the web page.  Note that the developer has the ability to specify how long a cookie should be saved on the user's system.  If you a timeout is not specified the cookie is not persisted to disk and lives within the memory of the user's browser, and will be destroyed when the browser is closed.

***Storing Web Application State in a Database***

It's also possible to store application state information in other places.  Sometimes one might want to maintain information over a very long time, which is the case with, for instance, user-related data.  In such cases, a developer would typically maintain this information in a database where it can be easily retrieved, modified, or deleted, and where it can be stably maintained over a long period of time (weeks, months, or years).

***What Should You Choose?***

In order to determine the best location where you should store your application's state information, in addition to considering the above information, you should also consider the following:

- Unless you take somewhat elaborate steps, data stored in Cookies persisted to the user's file system are stored clear-text and can be surreptitiously manipulated by the user.
- Data stored in the session object on the web server may cause you grief should you ever need to scale out your application to multiple web servers (a web farm).  The reason for this is because your user's subsequent web page requests may go to different web servers, and the most recent session information only exists on one of those servers.  There are mechanisms to deal with scaling out web applications that depend on session, but in general, you should probably try not to use session if you think you'll be scaling this application out to multiple web servers.

In the end, the choices you make are just that, your choices.  You will be best prepared to make those choices be becoming better educated on all the possibilities.

Good luck on your journey.

Comment: :Sor was busy,Jus now saw your post,So is it that it have to store the html design of the selected one in a state,and use it?